# WebDriver test open. Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to open using WebDriver this item?

```
<dl class="">
   <dt>
      <span class="sp_big login_title"></span>
     Login
      </dt>
   <dd style="display: none;">
</dl>
```

I try different ways and each time could not find the location of an item.

I wanted to do something like this but it does not work:

```
WebElement item = webdriver.find(By.className("sp_big login_title"));
item.click();
```

Comment: How to open using WebDriver this item? What does it mean? Please specify what action (e.g. click/input etc. etc.) you want to perform with this element.

Comment: Please also post the relevant code you've written so far while trying.

Comment: It is the structure of the page in which you will find a golf username and password. One must  to click on this structure, then eject panel  and then enter your password and login but do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided 2 class names together. Try the below.

```
WebElement item = webdriver.find(By.cssSelector("span.sp_big.login_title"));
item.click();
```